# What is the Delphi equivalent to C++ reference parameters?

Tags: c++, delphi

How do I write `int &a` in Delphi?

For example, in C++ it is `void ABC(int &a, int &b)`, but I don't know how to write it in Delphi.

Answer (score 7):

That is a reference parameter in C++. In Delphi that corresponds to a `var` [parameter](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/Parameters_%28Delphi%29#Value_and_Variable_Parameters).

```
procedure ABC(var a: Integer; var b: Integer);
```

The documentation says:

> Most parameters are either value parameters (the default) or variable (var) parameters. Value parameters are passed by value, while variable parameters are passed by reference.

Answer (score 4):

```
void ABC(int &a, int &b)
```

would become

```
procedure ABC(var a: Integer; var b: Integer);
```

The `var` keyword indicates that you wish to pass the value by reference, rather than value.

Comment: `procedure ABC(var a, b: Integer);` looks simpler.

Answer (score 1):

There is also `procedure ABC(out a: Integer; out b: Integer);`
While it is not exactly var-parameters, they also are going by-ref and intended to pass the value out. Depending on the semantics of the code you port, you may choose `var` or `out` on a case-by-case basis.

Comment: A Delphi `out` parameter for a value type like `Integer` is implemented exactly the same way as `var`. It's rather lame. But the C++ code is not like `out`. So I'm not sure why you mention it. There's also `const` etc. etc.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan `Inc(pointer)` and `Inc(integer)` are also implemented the same, which does not mean it is the same semantically. We do not know the semantical intention of topicstarter's code and we don't know if additional compiler control would help him or not. out is frequently overlooked feature and it does not hurt to learn it.

Comment: I'd argue that the implementation of `out` in Delphi makes it often be a mis-feature. Compare with C# and sigh.

Comment: Except for generic co-variance - the concepts Delphi lacks completely - i don;'t know what is the big difference from C# out. And eve nif Delphi's out is limited, that makes not it harmful like "misfeature" implies.

Comment: It is harmful because it has different meanings for managed types and unmanaged types. See if you can find documentation on that too. Generic co-variance and `inc` are un-related to the matter at hand.

Comment: Semantically `out` means that input value of a referenced parameter is ignored in a procedure. For managed types `out` implies overhead compared with `var` because the compiler cannot ignore a managed value due to built-in refcounting and insert additional code that nulls an `out` managed value outside of a procedure.
I don't think there is any reason to use `out` in a native Delphi code. `out` was introduced in the language to support `COM` and should be used there.

Comment: @Serg And of course Delphi just ignores `out` for an unmanaged type and has the same semantics as `var`.

Comment: `out` = `var` for unmanaged types; `out` = `var` + unnecessary overhead for managed types. So there is no reason to use `out` if you have no specific requirements like `COM` support.

Comment: @Serg That's actually a bad summary. There is a lot of value in `out`. It says that you cannot pass a value in to the function. Sadly it only has a difference for unmanaged types.

Comment: @LeonardoHerrera, @David - I've taken some time testing what out means in Delphi - http://sergworks.wordpress.com/2012/10/01/a-word-about-out-parameters-in-delphi/ . I was implementing a native Delphi interface and had to choose what to use - out or var - for interface methods` parameters. I had chosen to use var and never use out unless I have specific reason to do otherwise.

Comment: One may chose to always use `const` unless he has reasons not to, or waste type typing "const"s. Or one may choose to use mutable variables unless he has reasons to make them `const`s (i think  no other than making them by-ref). One can chose to make object fields public unless has reasons to make them private, or make them private unless he found reasons to privatize them. To me out is the contract i impose on myself. If Delphi is poor to implement it only in half of the cases - that mean the `out` keyword is half-beneficial, not half-harmful. I still fail to see how that keyword causes harm.

Comment: Also current Delphi seems to be in decline if not death spiral. DelphiII/LLVM ? FPC ? Oxygene? Smart Mobile ? who knows. But even if Delphi is broken here and there, unless that deficience causes harm, why not to enforce stricter rules that may be beneficial later ? it costs u nothing. http://pastebin.ca/2307068

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, the equivilent Delphi declaration is `procedure ABC(var a, b: Integer);`, **unless** your intention is to declare an external C/C++-implemented function that Delphi code can call into, in which case you have to take the C/C++ function's calling convention into account.  A Delphi function declaration that does not specify a calling convention, like above, uses Delphi's `register` calling convention (known as `__fastcall` in C++Builder).  The C/C++ declaration you show does not specify a calling convention, so the C/C++ compiler's default calling convention is used, which in most setups is `__cdecl`, in which case the equivilent Delphi declaration then becomes: `procedure ABC(var a, b: Integer); cdecl;`